# How do I use inheritance with a Jinja2 template encoded directly in a Python source code file?

Tags: python, inheritance, jinja2, template-engine

I have a base template `base.html` and a derived template `page2.html` that looks like this:

```
{# page2.html#}
{% extends "base.html" %}
{# end #}
```

I can render the template with:

```
jinjaEnv = Environment()
jinjaEnv.loader = FileSystemLoader('.')

@app.route('/page2')
def page2():
    page2Tem = jinjaEnv.get_template("page2.html")
    h = page2Tem.render()
    return h
```

And this works OK. But when I try:

```
nfpTem = Template("""\
{% extends "base.html" %}
stuff
""")
@app.route('/newfrontpage')
def frontPage():
    h = nfpTem.render()
    return h
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: no loader for this environment specified
```

How do I put a template in my Python source and use inheritance, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that jinja try to use a loader to find `'base.html'` here `{% extends "base.html" %}` on your template. If you want it to work you need to instantiate a loader, if you want embedded data on your python script one simple loader to use is `DictLoader` like on this example:

```
import jinja2

loader = jinja2.DictLoader(
    {'base': 
        'this will be filled {% block to_fill %}{% endblock %}',
     'child':
         '{% extends "base" %} {% block to_fill %}filled from child with value {{ value }}{% endblock %}'
    })
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)
print env.get_or_select_template('base').render()
print env.get_or_select_template('child').render(value='foo')
```